# Views not found everytime I copy laravel project to other system

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to move laravel project to other pc. After copying I run these commands

```
composer install
php artisan key:generate
php artisan cache:clear
```

then

```
php artisan serve
```

but it says

```
 (1/1) InvalidArgumentException

 View [auth.login] not found.
```

Even if I visit any other url it's view isn't found. What is wrong. What should be done?

Comment: did you try composer update ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, auth.login, myview, otherview, anyview... It gives exception on every view not only auths

Comment: Can you see the view files on the other pc?

Comment: @ThibaultDumas Why a composer update? It will update the packages which is not what the OP wants. The OP wants the application to work exactly as it worked on the other PC. When updating packages it could result in unwanted errors.

Comment: Yess they are there. I copied the whole project with .env files and also the vendor folder

Comment: @Stan Don't copy the vendor directory. Execute  `composer install` command instead.

Comment: If I don't copy the vendor folder then the changes I made on RegisterUser.php wouldnt be there on new files downloaded by composer install

Comment: You are not suposed to make changes to the vendor files.

Comment: php artisan config:cache , and try.

Comment: Try with `php artisan clear-compiled && php-artisan optimize`

Comment: Try running: `php artisan vendor:publish`

Comment: If you need to access the project from different conputers I recommend you to use github instead of copying the project.

Comment: `php artisan view:clear` might do the trick. As others have pointed out though this is not the way you should be distributing your app. Also, don't edit files in the vendor folder! If you want to make changes to the `RegisterUser` then just override the method in the RegisterController.

Comment: @RossWilson `php artisan view:clear` did the work, could you show how do I override the method in RegisterController,

Comment: I've added this as an answer for any one else who has a similar issue. As for `RegisterController` I would be happy to help if you create a new question (only because it goes outside of the scope of this one). :)

Answer (score 1):

> There are some points to remember.

Laravel compile the blade views and store these in `storage/framework/views` delete all the compiled views.

Make sure you don't have a typo in your file names because in Linux  `app.blade.php` and `App.blade.php` are different but in windows these are same.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you will need to clear your view cache.

To do this you will need to run:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Hope this helps!